# Rails attributes not being saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When trying to save a new entity (`Vote`) with AJAX calls, but the attributes are not being assigned.

Class and method being used:

```
class VoteController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :json

    def vote
        question_id = params[:question][:id]
        user_id = current_user.id
        vote = Vote.where(["question_id = :q", { q: question_id }]).where(["user_id = :u", { u: user_id }]).take
        respond_with do |format|
            if vote.nil?
                @vote = Vote.new
                @vote.question = question_id
                @vote.user = user_id
                @vote.save
                format.json { render :json => { :status => 'ok' } }
            else            
                format.json { render :json => { :status => 'failed', :msg => 'You already voted' } }
            end
        end
    end
end
```

The model:

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :question

    attr_accessor :user, :question
end
```

And the migration:

```
class CreateVotes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :votes do |t|
        t.references :question
        t.references :user
    end
  end
end
```

These are the parameters that are being sent:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "question"=>{"id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Up vote"}
```

With `puts` I tested that `current_user.id` indeed returns a value.

And here the query that is executed:

```
INSERT INTO `votes` VALUES ()
```

My records in the database:

```
+----+-------------+---------+
| id | question_id | user_id |
+----+-------------+---------+
|  1 |        NULL |    NULL |
|  2 |        NULL |    NULL |
|  3 |        NULL |    NULL |
|  4 |        NULL |    NULL |
|  5 |        NULL |    NULL |
|  6 |        NULL |    NULL |
|  7 |        NULL |    NULL |
+----+-------------+---------+
```

Why aren't these attributes being assigned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `attr_accessor :user, :question` is "covering up" ActiveRecord's methods of the same name.  Remove that line and try again.

Comment: and also change this `@vote.question = question_id` to this `@vote.question = Question.find question_id` ando also for user. Thanks